# Inserting new element to multi-dimensional array in php

Tags: php, html, arrays

```
<?php
  $accounts = [["felh" => "minta", "password" => "Meow123", "mail" => "pelda@gmail.com"],
  ["felh" => "minta2", "password" => "Meow1232", "mail" => "pelda2@gmail.com"]];
 if (isset($_POST["regisztral"])) {
    $username = $_POST["felh"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $email = $_POST["mail"];
    $password2 = $_POST["password2"];
       if (strlen($password) < 8)
       die("<b>error<b>");
       if ($password !== $password2)
       die("<b>error</b>");
        if ($_POST['feltetel'] != 'igen') die("<b>error</b>");
        foreach ($accounts as $account) {
        if ($account["felh"] === $username)     die("<b>error:</b> taken!");
         if ($account["mail"] === $email)     die("<b>error:</b>taken!");
        }

            $accounts[] = ["felh" => $username, "password" => $password, "mail" => $email];
        $file = fopen("accounts.txt", "w");
             foreach ($accounts as $account)
             fwrite($file, serialize($account) . "\n");
             fclose($file);

     echo "<br>Succeed<br/>";
     }
```

The user has to fill in a registration form and my program should decide whether his username and email adress are taken or not. I want to sort all usernames, passwords and email adresses into a 2 dimensional array and then write it into a text file. My problem is that every time I insert a new record into the array, it switches the last element to the one I just inserted instead of keeping it and adding the new element to the end of the array. How could I solve it?

*edit
I uploaded the entire php section of my code. So to be clear, my problem is the following: the 2 records I added manually at the beginning of the code work perfectly. When I want to insert let's say cat aaaaaaaa and nothing@gmail.com it Works perfectly. But when I submit another value after that, let's say dog bbbbbbbb and something@gmail.com it switches cat aaaaaaaaa and nothing@gmail.com to dog bbbbbbbb and something@gmail.com. What I want however is keeping cat aaaaaaaa nothing@gmail.com and THEN adding dog bbbbbbbb something@gmail.com to the end of the array

Comment: I don't see anything here that would replace a record. Assigning to `$accounts[]` always adds a new element.

Comment: Maybe the problem is with how you're reading from the file.

Comment: It will be help to solve your problem  if you show some example.

Comment: i edited it, so it's hopefully more understandable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is causing problem for you is php function fopen() and mode.
Currently in code you use mode 'w' and by php manual that mode is:

> Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file and truncate the file to zero length. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.

Everytime you overwrite this file named accounts.txt with new data.

So you should use mode 'a' to place pointer at the end of file and append new data.

> Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the end of the file. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it. In this mode, fseek() has no effect, writes are always appended.

test: https://repl.it/@kallefrombosnia/DiscreteOnerlookedLists

Comment: it looks better, but the program still throws no error messages when i try to insert usernames or emails that are already taken. in this example i can insert kale2 as many times as i want, the program will accept it, even though it should throw the message "error: taken"

Comment: It wont since you never check new values. You have 2 static values and always check against them, not new data in accounts.txt.

Check my demo example again.